# Add custom values to array

Tags: android

I have example android app:

```
void fillAutoCompleteFromDatabase()
{
    mCursor = mDB.query(
            PetType.PETTYPE_TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] {PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME, 
             PetType._ID}, null, null,
             null, null,
            PetType.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    startManagingCursor(mCursor);


    int iNumberOfSpeciesTypes = mCursor.getCount();
    String astrAutoTextOptions[] = new String[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes];
    if((iNumberOfSpeciesTypes > 0) && (mCursor.moveToFirst()))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < iNumberOfSpeciesTypes; i++)
        {
            astrAutoTextOptions[i] = 
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.
                           getColumnIndex(PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME));
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                astrAutoTextOptions);

        AutoCompleteTextView text = 
            (AutoCompleteTextView) 
                findViewById(R.id.EditTextSpecies);
        text.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

I'm still learning Android and i have question - why i can add custom values from this array? I try:

```
void fillAutoCompleteFromDatabase()
{
    mCursor = mDB.query(
            PetType.PETTYPE_TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] {PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME, 
             PetType._ID}, null, null,
             null, null,
            PetType.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    startManagingCursor(mCursor);


    int iNumberOfSpeciesTypes = mCursor.getCount();
    String astrAutoTextOptions[] = new String[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 3];
    if((iNumberOfSpeciesTypes > 0) && (mCursor.moveToFirst()))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < iNumberOfSpeciesTypes; i++)
        {
            astrAutoTextOptions[i] = 
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.
                           getColumnIndex(PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME));
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }

        astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 1] = "aaaaaa"; 
        astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 2] = "bbbb";
        astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 3] = "cccccc";

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                astrAutoTextOptions);

        AutoCompleteTextView text = 
            (AutoCompleteTextView) 
                findViewById(R.id.EditTextSpecies);
        text.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

I dont have error in Eclipse, but if i open this app on my mobile phone then she crashed.

Comment: You are missing an opening brace for the `for loop`.

Comment: Please, provide at least the exception message!!!

Comment: Sorry, brace exists. @Joseph i dont have exception message. First example working good. In second example i modify and added only working on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 1] = "aaaaaa"; 
    astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 2] = "bbbb";
    astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 3] = "cccccc";
```

to

```
    astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes] = "aaaaaa"; 
    astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 1] = "bbbb";
    astrAutoTextOptions[iNumberOfSpeciesTypes + 2] = "cccccc";
```

The for loop stops at the index for which the cursor doesn't have a value, that's the index you need to start writing to. However you are skipping that value and writing to the next 3, while only 2 are left available then.

I would advise you to change your whole code to this:

```
void fillAutoCompleteFromDatabase() {
    mCursor = mDB.query(
            PetType.PETTYPE_TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] {PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME,
                    PetType._ID}, null, null,
            null, null,
            PetType.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    startManagingCursor(mCursor);

    if(mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        List<String> astrAutoTextOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) {
            astrAutoTextOptions.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.
                    getColumnIndex(PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME)));
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }

        astrAutoTextOptions.add("aaaaaa");
        astrAutoTextOptions.add("bbbb");
        astrAutoTextOptions.add("cccccc");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                        astrAutoTextOptions);

        AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EditTextSpecies);
        text.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Lists are more portable in my opinion. Plus you were making some checks for your cursor.

One more thing. `startManagingCursor` is deprecated as far as i know. You shouldn't be using it. Instead use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).